# Postgresql : get notnull column value alone in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, coalesce

I have a table as below

| Id | String | Numeric | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 1006 | null |
| 2 | Testing value | null | null |
| 3 | null | null | 1-1-2023 |

`Id, String, Numeric, Date` are the column names. `Id` is the primary key. `Id` is going to have only one value (either string or numeric or date).

How to I get single value for single Id using select query leaving null values of other respective columns

I tried

```
select String OR Numeric OR Date 
from Table t 
where id = '2';
```

Comment: Please share the expected result

Comment: `COALESCE()` will solve. But the output will always be string-type.

Comment: If only one value can be not null, you shpuld think about your db design

Comment: expected result should be id:1 , value :1006 if id:2, value: testing value and if id:3, value: 1-1-2023

Comment: Looks like a problem with your datamodel. It’s extremely rare that you don’t know what you’re looking for. Let’s say you get the value 25 as a result, what is it? Your string value or numerical value?

Comment: What happens **when** two or even all three columns have non-null values. To prevent this check out the [num_nulls function()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) as a check constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the coalesce function to do this

```
select COALESCE(String, Numeric::text, Date::text) 
from Table t 
where id = '2';
```

This will give back the first non-null value out of the three columns or null if all three columns are null. The output of this query is a string however, so depending on your application you might have the recast the result back again later. You could also consider using a case instead

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN string IS NOT NULL THEN string
         WHEN numeric IS NOT NULL THEN numeric::string
         WHEN date IS NOT NULL THEN date::string 
         ELSE NULL 
    END 
FROM
    Table t 
WHERE
    id = '2';
```

This will get very messy when there are lots of columns so I wouldn't recommend it in general, but it does allow for some extra flexibility on the output if required.